# How to declare an unsigned long long in Protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, long-long

What is the right way to declare an unsigned LongLong (unsigned __int64) in Protobuf, so it would be used for both, Android and Windows?

**EDIT:**
I thought that I might need to use to variables, each holds a uint64, but I wasn't sure if this is the correct way to go.

**UPDATE**

I used uint64 in the protobuf file and compile it. the result in the cpp file was unsigned __int64. I got confused because in the docs they say it is mapped to long..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) clearly lists the available scalar types.

Not sure exactly what you're after, but perhaps `uint64`?

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for decleration of unsigned long long, and uint64 is just unsigned long..

Comment: @user844541 `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have a size of 64 bits nothing more!

Comment: and uint64 is guaranteed to have 64 bits?

Comment: @user844541 certainly on the wire it is; one *assumes* that implementations with a 64-bit type would use it